# Listing an optional Python dependency in setup.py

Tags: python, modules, installer

I have a small project that requires a third-party module that's rarely updated (once every other year or so) and not maintained by any package management system. The context, here, is cognitive science & research, the third party module is for linking proprietary hardware to custom scripting, in the house project, potentially, may end up seeing wider (eventually open source) use within cog. psych so I want to plan for distribution.

Can anyone poke holes in or thumbs up this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

try:
    import third_party_package
    install_packages = ['in_house_package']
except ImportError:
    print "Warning: 'third_party_package' not found in PYTHON_PATH, installing version in_house_package v. <VERSION>"
    install_packages = ['in_house_package', 'in_house_package.third_party_package']

setup(
    name='InHousePackage', 
    version = '0.1', 
    description = 'A framework for building psychological experiments in Python', 
    author = 'me', 
    author_email = 'my_address', 
    url = 'a local git', 
    packages=install_packages,
    requires = ['numpy']
    )
```

Comment: Do you have any plans of moving to python3 in the future?

Comment: For this project, no, alas; the `third_party_package` is critical and will, almost certainly, never be updated to Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few small comments:

1. **The error message looks wrong to me.**

   This is what the logic looks like to me:

   ```
   if (third party package is installed):
       install(in-house package)
   else:
       install(in-house package)
       install(in-house variant of third-party package)
   ```

   but the printed warning tells me that the in-house package isn’t installed. Shouldn’t it tell me the third-party package isn’t installed?
2. **An ImportError doesn’t necessarily mean a module isn’t installed.**

   It just indicates any error when the module was imported. For example, if I have a file `foo.py` that contains:

   ```
   import bar
   ```

   and no module `bar.py`, I get an ImportError when trying to import foo, even though the foo file exists:

   ```
   >>> import foo
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
       import bar
   ImportError: No module named bar
   ```

   You can jump through hoops with import tools, or check the error message of the ImportError. That may or may not be something worth worrying about; just remember that this edge case is there.
3. **Trivial nitpicks.**

   - I’m sure this is just an artefact of posting on CR, and it isn’t actually called `in_house_package`, but you’ve misspelt it in the error message.
   - When specifying keyword arguments to a function (such as `setup()`), it’s common to omit the spaces around the equals sign.